# Как сложить значение двух массивов по ключам?

Tags: php

Есть массив bestliker со значениями `array(3) { [23946139]=> int(5) [2582866]=> int(5) [156444354]=> int(4) }` и массив bestcommentator `array(4) { [23946139]=> int(4) [2582866]=> int(6) [156444354]=> int(4)  [25828612]=> int(8) }`
Я хочу получить массив result `array(4) { [23946139]=> int(9) [2582866]=> int(11) [156444354]=> int(8) [25828612]=> int(8) }`
У меня получилось сложить только значение value если key равны.

```
$result = array();
    foreach ($bestliker as $key => $value) {
        $result_count_liker_id = $key;
        $result_count_liker = $value;
        if ($result_count_liker > 0) {
            foreach ($bestcommentator as $key2 => $value2) {
                $result_count_comment_id = $key2;
                $result_count_comment = $value2;
                if ($result_count_liker_id == $result_count_comment_id ) {
                    $result= $result_count_liker + $result_count_comment;
                    var_dump($result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать `isset`, чтобы проверить, существует ли переменная

Адаптация ответа [от сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/sum-array-values-of-the-same-key):

```
$result  = array();
$input= array($bestliker,$bestcommentator);

array_walk_recursive($input, function($item, $key) use (&$final){
    $final[$key] = isset($final[$key]) ?  $item + $final[$key] : $item;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо ,а то я уже хотел делать array_merge для ключей , потом по ним искать значения и складывать ..